# How to create a custom validation rule comparing against a column?

Tags: php, laravel

I want do something like `exist:table,column` but, with the rule `gte:field`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures). Going off your example image:

```
[
    'quantity' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $instance = Product::find($this->input('product_id'));
  
            if ($instance->getAttribute('price') > $value) {
              $fail($attribute.' must be greater than or equal to price.');
            }
        }
    ]
]
```